# Encoding pdf in utf-8 with wkhtmltopdf in Java

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, wkhtmltopdf

I've had GWT, ext-GWT web-project in utf-8 charset. I've also add utf-8 charset in html file.

Additionally I need to create some pdf report. So that I wrote a special servlet, which take a template html-file, add some information (in **local** language) and convert a new *generated* html-file to pdf-file with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Now, when I try to convert that *generated* html-file (which also had `<meta charset="UTF-8">`) to pdf-file, **information with local language** (some *Strings*), which I send from client code to servlet is replacing in the result pdf-file with "?" symbol in a black rhomb.

To solve this problem I add some parameters to Process Builder such as `"--encoding"` `"utf-8"`:

```
private void ConvertHTMLtoPDF(String sConvertationProgramm, String sHTML, String sPDF)
{
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(sConvertationProgramm, "--encoding", "utf-8", sHTML, sPDF);
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but all the same, there is no effect at all. At the same time I have those symbols only on tomcat server, without same trouble at jetty.

---

So, Where is the problem, on the sending local information to the server (cause another information in a local language from template html-file is showed correctly) or when it's writing/converting at the server side?

Does anyone has any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. And I have to give my ***apologises*** for everyone, because my problem was in the writing new generated html, so instead of using this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fHTML));
```

I must use this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF8"));
BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fHTML), "UTF-8"));
```

So, the problem was on reading/writing html-files.